# Declaring required mutually exclusive options with ManyConsole

Tags: command-line-arguments, ndesk.options, manyconsole

I am using the excellent [ManyConsole](https://github.com/fschwiet/ManyConsole) extension to the great [Mono.Options](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/Mono.Options)

I was wondering whether it supports mutually exclusive required options. I think that `Mono.Options` does not support them and hence `ManyConsole` probably does not either.

But I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can override OverrideAfterHandlingArgumentsBeforeRun with custom validation and throw a ConsoleAsHelpException if it fails.  Thanks for the positive feedback on the library though I am falling behind on handling PRs.